# Strange behavior by tween.js animation

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, rotation, tween.js

I am rotating a cube by 90 degrees using tween.js but there are these things that are not working as expected,
I am using this code:

```
var start = {x:cube[1].rotation.x, y:cube[1].rotation.y, z:cube[1].rotation.z};
var end = {x:cube[1].rotation.x, y:cube[1].rotation.y + degreeToRadians(90),z:cube[1].rotation.z};

var tween = new TWEEN.Tween(start)
  .to(end, 1000)
  .easing( TWEEN.Easing.Exponential.InOut )
  .onUpdate(function(){
     cube[1].rotation.x = this.x;
     cube[1].rotation.y = this.y;
     cube[1].rotation.z = this.z;
   })
.start()
console.log(cube[1].rotation.y);
```

by using this the cube rotates by 90 degress along y axis 
but in the console it gives value for rotation 0
and when i rotate it again as many times it adds 1.570796 to the rotation value every time.So, I am confused why it does not add this value only the first time.

So to solve the problem i did this

```
cube[1].rotation.y+=1.57079632679;    //1
```

i added this after every rotation but instead of increasing the value every time which should create problem after first rotation it only increases it once.Value of cube[1].rotation.y goes like this

rotation   1st
before rotation  0
after rotation  1.57....  //because of 1

rotation   2nd
before rotation  1.57....
after rotation  3.14....  //when it should have been 3.14...+ 1.57...

and so my code works even though it shouldn't
and if i add 1.57 only after the first rotation,the rotation lags by 1.
So can anyone explain this.

And when I added this

```
cube[1].rotation.y+=1.57079632679;
```

Shouldn't it supposed to not only increase its value but rotate the cube without any animation as well but instead it only does the first part.Why?

EDIT

Actually i haven't placed it in render function but instead I am rotating it on mouse click,here is the code for it:

```
var mouseDown = false,
pageX = 0;

function onMouseDown(evt)
{
    evt.preventDefault();

    mouseDown = true;
    pageY = evt.pageY;
    pageX = evt.pageX;

    var x = event.x;
    var y = event.y;

    mouse.x = ( event.clientX / renderer.domElement.clientWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / renderer.domElement.clientHeight ) * 2 + 1;

    raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );
    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( objects );

    if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
        if(intersects[ 0 ].object==cube[1])
        {
            move();
        }
    }
}

function move (){

var start = {x:cube[1].rotation.x, y:cube[1].rotation.y, z:cube[1].rotation.z};
var end = {x:cube[1].rotation.x  , y:cube[1].rotation.y + degreeToRadians(90),
          z:cube[1].rotation.z};

var tween = new TWEEN.Tween(start)
  .to(end, 1000)
  .easing( TWEEN.Easing.Exponential.InOut )
  .onUpdate(function(){
     cube[1].rotation.x = this.x;
     cube[1].rotation.y = this.y;
     cube[1].rotation.z = this.z;
   })
.start()

console.log(cube[1].rotation.y); 

cube[1].rotation.y+=1.57079632679;

console.log(cube[1].rotation.y);
}

function degreeToRadians(degrees) {
    return degrees * Math.PI / 180;
}

function onMouseUp(evt)
{
    evt.preventDefault();

    mouseDown = false;

}

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    render();
    stats.update();

}

function render() {
    TWEEN.update();
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

Comment: Can you post your complete render loop code? I'd like to know where you declare the tween object and where you print the console log.

Comment: @DavideNecchi thankyou for taking out time to help me, I have added my code in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to move the increment of Y rotation before the tween

```
function move (){

cube[1].rotation.y+=1.57079632679; // HERE !!!

var start = {x:cube[1].rotation.x, y:cube[1].rotation.y, z:cube[1].rotation.z};
var end = {x:cube[1].rotation.x  , y:cube[1].rotation.y + degreeToRadians(90),
          z:cube[1].rotation.z};

var tween = new TWEEN.Tween(start)
  .to(end, 1000)
  .easing( TWEEN.Easing.Exponential.InOut )
  .onUpdate(function(){
     cube[1].rotation.x = this.x;
     cube[1].rotation.y = this.y;
     cube[1].rotation.z = this.z;
   })
.start()

console.log(cube[1].rotation.y); 
// NOT HERE !!!!
console.log(cube[1].rotation.y);
}
```

In your code you correct rotate the cube by 90°, but at the first render loop the rotation is forced to the tween count value.
Moving first you start the tween with the correct value (rotation + 90°)

I hope I understood your problem!

Comment: Sorry,you are not getting it,what i am trying to say is why do I even need cube[1].rotation.y+=1.57... ,when tween is already doing it except it skips doing it the first time and isn't  cube[1].rotation.y+=1.57...  supposed to rotate the cube by specified value so why double rotation don't occurs?

Comment: you are usein the increment twice, i think that if you comment the  first one



`console.log(cube[1].rotation.y); 
cube[1].rotation.y+=1.57079632679;
console.log(cube[1].rotation.y);`

you have the same result, it's true?

Comment: That is what I'm saying that even when I'm using the increment twice once by tween and other directly,it isn't rotating it twice it only rotates it once by the tween function.

Comment: To make myself clear i have some screenshots the link is [link](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B-A8PSYZEySfNjU2aUxzYW1IdDQ&usp=sharing)   you will notice in image 12 that even after rotation value does not gets incremented but gets incremented on 2nd rotation in image 13,and in image 22 when i add   cube[1].rotation.y+=1.57079632679; it increments the value but this does not rotates the cube and in image 23 neither this increments the value nor does it rotates the cube(note that value becomes 3.1415.. but this is due to the tween rotation not this) this is strange!!

Comment: It's correct, you start tween from 0 to 1.57... then you increment the rotation by 1.57 (on line 284).. but until you render you don't view the rosult. But before the render you apply the tween update resetting the rotation value in a range from 0 to 1.57. On the second rotation you start the tween from 1.57 to 3.14, you apply the rotation in line 284, but in the firse tween update the value is resetted to range 1.57 - 3.14 in according to tween count.

Comment: oh i think you are right,i didn't knew about the resetting by tween update,thanx for clearing this for me.